# How to calculate the solid angle of a rectangle?

Tags: geometry, 3d, angle, solid-angle

Let $R$ be a rectangle with vertices $\boldsymbol{n}_1$, $\boldsymbol{n}_2$, $\boldsymbol{n}_3$ and $\boldsymbol{n}_4 \in \mathbb{R}^3$. I am looking for a formula for calculating the solid angle subtended by $R$ at a point $\boldsymbol{p}\in \mathbb{R}^3$. The solid angle can be calculated as
$$\Omega(R)=\int \int_R \frac{\boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{p}}{\left \Vert \boldsymbol{x}-\boldsymbol{p} \right \Vert_2^3 } \boldsymbol{\cdot n} dS(\boldsymbol{x}), $$
where $\boldsymbol{n} = \boldsymbol{n}(\boldsymbol{x})$ is the unit normal of $R$ at $\boldsymbol{x} \in R$. The rectangle $R$ has a parametrisation
$$ \boldsymbol{s}(u, v) = u (\boldsymbol{n}_1 -\boldsymbol{n}_2)+v(\boldsymbol{n}_3 - \boldsymbol{n}_2)+\boldsymbol{n}_2 ,$$
where $(u, v)\in [0, 1]^2$.

However, calculating the surface integral seems to be difficult even for a calculator. Can the solid angle be given in a closed form in this general setting, or does one have to rely on approximation/numerical integration?

Comment: You can divide the pyramid formed by the rectangle $R$ and the point $p$, into two tetrahedrons, for which you can compute the exact value of the solid angle using the formula  $ \Omega = A + B + C - \pi $, where $A, B,C $ are the the three angles between the three planes (for each tetrahedron) sharing the apex $p$.

Comment: Or better still... the solid angle for the rectangle is given by $$ \Omega = A + B + C + D - 2 \pi $$  where $A,B,C,D$ are the angles between the lateral planes of pyramid formed by the rectangle $R$ and the point $p$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Eriksson](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/Eriksson14108673.pdf) derived a simple formula for the solid angle $E$ of a planar triangle in terms of unit vectors $a,b,c$ from the origin to the three vertices:
$$\tan \frac E 2 = \frac {\vert a \cdot b \times c \vert} {1+b \cdot c+c \cdot a + a \cdot b}$$
The OP could separate the  rectangle into two planar triangles by drawing a diagonal across, then use the Eriksson formula on each.